# Set Facebook Application ID dynamically in flutter for iOS

Tags: swift, flutter, facebook-sdk-4.0

My iOS application requires multiple Facebook Applications. But, since we have to put the application ID and client ID on the info.plist file. So, it's impossible to switch or change the application ID without a dynamic way.

As per facebook documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.24/class/FBSettings/), I found there is a method named `setAppID`/`setDefaultAppID`. Through this, I should be able to change the Facebook application ID dynamically. But, in the **FBSDKCoreKit** package, there are no such methods.

I tried:

- `FBSDKCoreKit.Settings.setAppID("appID")` [No such method]
- `FBSDKCoreKit.Settings().setAppID("appID")` [No such method]
- `FBSDKCoreKit.Settings.appId = "appID"` [Doesn't work]
- `FBSDKCoreKit.Settings.shared.appId = "appID"` [iOS application crashes]